# java DataInputStream read() stop and do not proceed

Tags: java, sockets, object, file-io, datainputstream

- I want sends and receive an object and file the order is

  1. client -> server   by ObjectOut(In)putStream
  2. client -> server String(file name) by DataIn(Out)putStrean writeUTF
  3. client -> server  by BufferedIn(Out)putStream
  4. server -> client  by ObjectOut(In)putStream

but when the code reaches on 3 writing file takes forever (I think...it is waiting) the critical code is

```
byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
while ((length = bis.read(data)) != -1) {
    bos.write(data, 0, length);
    System.out.println(length);
}
```

`bis(BufferedInputStream).read()` do not proceed when I print the length the output is

```
4096
4096
879
```

then just wait...

is there anyone who knows what is the problem or solution?

**Server thread**

```
public void run() {

    System.out.println("\n New FileUploadServer thread started");
    msg = (Message) objComm.recvObject(clientSocket);
    System.out.println("server get message");
    if (checkState(msg.getState()))
        System.out.println(clientAddr + " session over");

    System.out.println("");
}

private boolean checkState(int _state) {
    switch (_state) {
        case ST_EXCEL_FILE:
            return receiveExcel();
        default:
            return false;
    }
}


private boolean receiveExcel() {

    Message sendMsg = receiveStr();
    System.out.println("receiveStr() success");
    BufferedInputStream bis;
    DataOutputStream dos;
    DataInputStream dis;
    FileOutputStream fos;
    BufferedOutputStream bos;

    VoteInfo sendVoteInfo = (VoteInfo) msg.getObj();

    try {
        dis = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        dos = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        // check file name extension is "xls" or "xlsx"
        String fName = dis.readUTF();


        int idx = fName.lastIndexOf(".");
        String extension = fName.substring(idx + 1, fName.length());
        if (!excelFileCheck(extension))
            return false;

        dos.writeUTF("read_ok");
        dos.flush();
        System.out.println("File name: " + fName);
        File f = new File(EXCEL_FILE_DIR + fName);

        fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

        int length;
        byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        while ((length = bis.read(data)) != -1) {
            bos.write(data, 0, length);
            System.out.println(length);
        }
        bos.flush();
        // send success message to web server
        System.out.println("kangji2");

        objComm.sendObject(sendMsg, clientSocket);


        System.out.println("File receive success!");

        if (!dataToDB.excelToDB(EXCEL_FILE_DIR + fName, extension)) {
            //delete all db related to this excel file here
            return false;
        } else {


        }
        bos.close();
        fos.close();
        dis.close();

        clientSocket.close();

        // send candidates information to DB server
        return makeResult(sendVoteInfo);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("ReceiveExcel error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}


public class ObjectComm {

    private Message receiveMsg = null;
    private ObjectOutputStream out = null;
    private ObjectInputStream in = null;

    public Message commObject(Message _sendMsg, Socket _clntSocket) {

        if (!_clntSocket.isConnected()) {
            System.out.println("clnt Socket not connected");
            return null;
        }

        try {
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(_clntSocket.getOutputStream());
            out.writeObject(_sendMsg);
            out.flush();

            System.out.println("kangji1");
            in = new ObjectInputStream(_clntSocket.getInputStream());
            receiveMsg = (Message) in.readObject();
            System.out.println("kangji2");
            return receiveMsg;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("commObject err");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }

    public boolean sendObject(Message _msg, Socket _clntSocket) {
        if (!_clntSocket.isConnected()) {
            System.out.println("clnt Socket not connected");
            return false;
        }

        try {
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(_clntSocket.getOutputStream());
            out.writeObject(_msg);
            out.flush();

            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Object comm send err");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Message recvObject(Socket _clntSocket) {
        if (!_clntSocket.isConnected()) {
            System.out.println("clnt Socket not connected");
            return null;
        }

        try {
            in = new ObjectInputStream(_clntSocket.getInputStream());
            receiveMsg = (Message) in.readObject();
            return receiveMsg;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Object comm recvObject err");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you close the connection in client side (sender side, or wherever opposite of your input stream) ? read(byte[], int, int ) in BufferedInputStream will return when end of the stream has been reached.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html#read(byte[],%20int,%20int)

Comment: I thought if I close buffers then socket is closed also
isn't it?

Comment: Well, I don't see close() call for BufferedInputStream in your code.. and actually you shouldn't do that. Your code need to read input stream until read() return -1 and then you can close input stream at the end of your code, not during you read bytes from input stream.

Try to add socket close logic in opposite part where your code read bytes through input stream, and retry if my suggestion works.

Comment: As you said if I add close() the waiting is over but the problem is after close(), socket also closed. so I can't receive or get messsage from server after close()

Comment: Seems like your client side that you connect with clientSocket is finished sending data and there is nothing left. So every time your code try to read bytes through read(byte[], int, int), methods will return 0(zero) since there is nothing to read and reading is actually blocked. That's why you don't see any data after 4096 4096  879.

As you commented, if you want to keep using that connected clientSocket, then yes you shouldn't close the socket. Simply changing while conditions like while((length = bis.read(data)) > 0) ... you might able to avoid current problem,

Comment: Although there are possibility that your network or client side remote process is actually blocked for some reason and not sending anything temporary.. that case your reading process will be finished  even if there are still more bytes to read.

Comment: thanks for your comments but..while((length = bis.read(data)) > 0) doesn't work. same result.

Comment: if I delete the code after file communcation, 
it works correctly. so..I think, it's not network problem..

Comment: Your read() call will be "blocked" and not getting any return value unless your close socket / inpustream OR client close the connection. ( that way your code get -1 ).
So yes, even > 0 check won't fix your problem since your code is still waiting to get some bytes from client side. You may need to redesign your protocol so once you get any kind of END-OF-SENDING notification, your stop reading it and start writing in another thread? ( use thread and/or nonblocking io for that )

Answer (score 0):

> - client -> server by ObjectOut(In)putStream
> - client -> server String(file name) by DataIn(Out)putStrean writeUTF
> - client -> server by BufferedIn(Out)putStream
> - server -> client by ObjectOut(In)putStream

Too much stuff here.

Playing with streams at different levels of your stream stack ***simply does not work.***

If you want to send objects, use the `ObjectInput/OutputStreams` for *everything.* Construct them as follows:

```
new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(...))
```

and

```
new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(...))
```

Send the objects with `writeObject();` send the strings with `writeObject()` or `writeUTF();` send byte arrays via `ObjectOutputStream.write();` and use the complementary methods of `ObjectInputStream` at the other end.

Comment: You tried what exactly? What code? Edit it into your question.